# SATA Hard Drive reading and writing at <1mb speeds

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I just built a new PC, and it seemed to be doing great until I ran CrystalDiskMark on my disk drive. Here are the results:

Run with 1GiB test

SEQ, Q32t: R: 110.8 W: 89.48

4K, Q32T1: R: 0.926 W: 0.759

Seq: R: 75.28 W:99.61

4K: R: 0.304 W: 0.806

All speeds are in MB/s. Please help!

Comment: Please add some specifications to your question, like make and model of motherboard, hard drive, etc.  Otherwise how anyone know if these results are normal or not?

Answer (score 1):

Sequential read at 75MB/s looks a bit low for a new drive.  You provided no information at all about hardware, OS, config, drivers, what controller they're plugged in to, etc.)   So there's nothing I can add about your HW.

My Toshiba 3TiB DT01ACA300 drives get ~190MB/s sequential read/write at the beginning of the disk (Linux, Intel SnB i5-2500k in an Intel DZ68DB mobo, dual channel DDR3-1600.  Drives plugged in to the usual chipset SATA ports of the Z68 chipset).

0.3MB/s for random read with 4k blocks sounds reasonable.  You know seeking is slow, right?  That's why SSDs are awesome.  0.3MB/s * 1/4kiB = 75 IOs / sec.  That's in the [range wikipedia's table of examples lists for a 7200RPM hard drive.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS#Mechanical_hard_drives)

Comment: AH ok, i have an i7 3.4 Ghz processor with 18 gig ram, a gigabyte z97-hd3 motherboard, and have the HDD set up as ahci. windows 10 as well

Comment: @Nealio: and what model of hard drive?  The hard drive itself is usually the most important factor in hard drive speed.

Comment: Seagate Barracuda VS2263

Comment: @Nealio: ok, now go google up some HD benchmark reports for that drive, and see what they look like.  You're probably not the first person to benchmark that drive and put the result on the Internet.  Also, edit that info into the question.  It's buried down here.

Comment: So the average SEQ r is 163, and w is 157.  So what I'm getting is not terrible, its just not great.  Would reseating the cable be a good option?

Comment: @Nealio Yes, reseat the cable, and if that doesn't fix the problem try a new/different SATA cable. I've seen it myself first hand where a faulty cable has reduced transfer speeds. Also, your BIOS settings may have your SATA ports operating in IDE Emulation mode. That *can* affect max speed, so try AHCI mode if possible.